# Find global minimum of discretely defined function

Tags: python, scipy, genetic-algorithm, mathematical-optimization

I have a four parameter function for which I do not have the mathematical form because it is actually the result of several separate processes. In its simplest form it can be thought of as a black box which returns a value that depends on the values of the parameters `a,b,c,d` it is called with. This is what it looks like:

```
def my_func(a, b, c, d):
    # Make lots of calculations here to come up with 'func_value',
    # which depends on the values of the parameters given a,b,c,d.
    func_value = x(a, b, c, d)
    return func_value
```

The space of those four parameters is restricted not only in range but it is also discrete. This means that the parameters can have certain values:

```
a = [0.004, 0.006, 0.008, 0.010, ...]
b = [0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.35, ...]
c = [0.0, 0.01, 0.02, 0.03, ...]
b = [10.1, 10.2, 10.3, 10.4, ...]
```

and not those in between (ie: they vary in *steps*).

I need to find the *global minimum* for this function, ie: the set composed of those particular parameters values `[a_i,b_j,c_k,d_l]` that returns the minimum value possible for `my_func`.

I know of the existence of algorithms such as [scipy.optimize.anneal](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.anneal.html) or genetic algorithms like those defined in [DEAP](https://code.google.com/p/deap/), [PyBrain](http://pybrain.org/docs/api/optimization/optimization.html?highlight=genetic#population-based) or [Pyevolve](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/intro.html#ga-features) that should be applicable to this kind of optimization problems.

What I'm not sure of is which one I could use having in mind the restrictions imposed by my code, ie: multiple (four) parameters function with no mathematical form, restricted and discrete spaces for the parameters.

Reviewing all of those methods can take a lot of time, so any pointers as to what I should probably be trying to apply will be much appreciated.

Comment: Do you need to find the exact global minimum or is a probabilistic result sufficient? Do you have no information about the function structure at all? Do you expect the function to heavily vary for neighbouring inputs or is it rather smooth? How big is your search space? (How many dimensions and how many points per dimension?) Are the dimensions strongly correlated or nearly separable?

Comment: A probabilistic result is sufficient (as I understand it, I can get more precision if needed by increasing the number of runs for the algorithm) I have no precise information about the structure of the function other than it _should_ vary smoothly for neighboring inputs. The search space is four dimensional (given by the four parameters) and the number of points per dimension is adjustable but I expect it to not get over 1e6 points in total (ie: the multiplication of the number of points in each dimension should stay below that value).

Comment: If you'd be willing to run through all possible values this shouldn't be too difficult to calculate. Can you give the start and end points of a,b,c,d and the step size? And though you call x a black box, can we call x?

Comment: Since your four parameters are bounded _and_ change by a fixed increment, you only have a finite number of possible value combinations. Of course this number might be very large, but you should consider whether exhaustive search is a possibility.

Comment: I've tried the brute force approach but it takes ~0.5sec for each evaluation of `my_func` which makes it not feasible, specially considering the whole process needs to be run a couple hundred times inside a bootstrap `for` loop.

Comment: The calculations needed for the brute-force approach are probably very repetitive. You should still take a good look at organizing your calculations in a way that lest you cache and reuse partial result calculations ("memoizing" is one approach in python). For example, there may be several expensive quantities dependent on `a`, `b` and `c` only, which you'll need to combine with _every_ value of `d`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All "hill-climbing" algorithms depend on the assumption that small changes in the input result in (typically) small changes in the output. Your description of the problem includes absolutely no restrictions on the form of the function graph (except for your interest in probabilistic hill climbing, which implies that it does apply to your domain). You couldn't use hill climbing on a cryptographic hash function, for example.

But the best algorithm depends largely on additional characteristics of the problem:

1. Simulated annealing starts with large "jumps" that get progressively smaller, the idea being that you end up on the largest "hill" (or valley, since you formulate your goal as a minimum) before your jumps get too small and you get trapped there.
2. The genetic algorithm is good when the different parameters, or groups of them, are semi-independent of each other. The idea is that the small groups of parameters can be independently optimized by local hill-climbing, and the recombination function may bring together several optimized sub-groups to produce a super-solution. It is useless if all parameters are tightly coupled.

Other algorithms are similarly best suited to different problem profiles. (And unfortunately, your problem description doesn't seem to include the relevant properties.)

In short: While a mathematical formula is not a requirement, you do need some understanding of how the graph of your function behaves, and any projection invariants (quantities that contribute to `x` but do not depend on all four parameters `a, b, c, d`). This last will also be helpful for speeding up the calculation of the function's values, which as you say is extremely expensive. I would suggest you at least graph some low-resolution slices across your search space. They might give you some ideas.

PS. If the quality of the solution is more important than calculation time, you could always implement *several* approaches, run them in parallel, and keep the best solution.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations Alexis.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned it is a common optimization problem. The mathematical formula is very rarely required, since in practice we rarely have it. One important feature which simplifies a lot is the convexity of the function (again you don't need to think of it in terms of mathematical formulas but rather if the global maximum is unique).

For the beginning I would suggest one of following classical algorithms:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabu_search
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms